# How to compare row values with group value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
   ...:                    'B': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2'],
   ...:                    'X': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   ...:                    'Y': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
   ...:                    'Z': [4, 5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5]})
Out[35]: 
   A   B  X  Y  Z
0  A  C1  0  1  4
1  B  C1  0  1  5
2  C  C1  1  1  2
3  D  C1  1  0  1
4  E  C2  0  1  2
5  F  C2  1  1  1
6  G  C2  0  0  3
7  H  C2  0  1  5
```

I want to select all rows by group (column B) where column Y equals 1 **AND**

(cumsum of column Z) < (10 - sum of column Z where X==1)

I tried

```
(df.Y==1) & ((df[df.Y==1].groupby('B')['Z'].cumsum()) <= (10 - df[df.X==1].groupby('B')['Z'].sum()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-36-5be310568c09>", line 1, in <module>
    df['S'] = (df.Y==1) & ((df[df.Y==1].groupby('B')['Z'].cumsum()) <= (10 - df[df.X==1].groupby('B')['Z'].sum()))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 524, in wrapper
    raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

this works

```
(df.Y==1) & ((df[df.Y==1].groupby('B')['Z'].cumsum()) <= 10)
Out[39]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

but this is only checks whether (cumsum <= 10) but not (10 minus the sum df.Z where df.X==1)

what is the right approach of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This approach creates 2 new columns, then uses the values in them to filter the dataframe. The new columns:

•'Z_cumsum': cumulative sum of 'Z', by group in 'B', when 'Y' = 1

•'Z_sum': sum of values of Z, per group in 'B', only including the values in Z where

```
df['Z_cumsum'] = np.nan
df.loc[df.Y==1, 'Z_cumsum'] = df[df.Y==1].groupby('B')['Z'].cumsum()

df['Z_sum'] = np.nan
for b in set(df['B']):
    df.loc[df.B==b,'Z_sum'] = df.loc[df['X']==1].groupby('B')['Z'].sum()[b]
df
```

The new dataframe:

```
    A   B   X   Y   Z   Z_cumsum    Z_sum
0   A   C1  0   1   4   4.0         3.0
1   B   C1  0   1   5   9.0         3.0
2   C   C1  1   1   2   11.0        3.0
3   D   C1  1   0   1   NaN         3.0
4   E   C2  0   1   2   2.0         1.0
5   F   C2  1   1   1   3.0         1.0
6   G   C2  0   0   3   NaN         1.0
7   H   C2  0   1   5   8.0         1.0
```

Now you can more easily filter the dataframe:

```
(df.Y==1) & (df['Z_cumsum'] <= (10- df['Z_sum']))

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

I understand it is a rather cumbersome approach, but it is what I was able to get.

Comment: hi. thanks for your answer but the value subtracted from '10' should be the sum of 'Z' within each group (column B) where X==1 and not the overall sum of column X, so in my example for group C1 the value is 3 (2+1) and for group C2 it is 1

Comment: My bad. Please check the edit, hopefully it helps. It is a Microsoft Excellish approach, adding new columns

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `groupby().apply()` and use your logice:

```
mask = (df.loc[df['Y']==1]
   .groupby('B')
   .apply(lambda x: x['Z'].cumsum() + x['Z']*x['X'].eq(1) < 10)
   .reset_index('B', drop=True)
    & df['Y'].eq(1)
)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. in my actual code column X and Z are actually in another df. how can I apply it then? also X is not a 1/0 value but any value and i just want to add up if X has any value and is not nan. it would help me if you could follow my logic in my example where I get ValueError. thanks

Comment: my problem is really how can I compare row value of a group with a specific value for this this group with each group having been assigned a different value